# How do you put a period after the section number using the article class?

Tags: latex

I am using the article class with the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
This is an example of foo.
\section{Bar}
This is an example of bar.
\end{document}
```

This produces:

1   Foo

2   Bar

What I want is a period after the section number:

1. Foo
2. Bar

I cannot change away from the article class. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
```

Comment: You do **NOT** want to do this! Definitely not the right answer: `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} \renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.} \section{foo}\label{foo} this is section~\ref{foo}.\end{document}`

Comment: it worked, kind of. I wrote another line of code to remove the "." from the subsection command. Using just this line of code with the subsection command got me 2..1 Bar. I changed it though. it's hacky, but it worked.

Answer (score 8):

Use the *titlesec* package and put in the preamble:

```
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, since I have still no latex in my, reformatted, pc but it should be something like:

```
\def\thesection {\arabic{section}.}
```

You should put it in preamble of document. Absolutely not sure about correctness (no way to try it now).

Comment: Nope, this adds the period after a \ref{} as well.